# webmin and reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, webmin

I want to proxy a `webmin` endpoint eg. `https://xx.xx.xx.xx:10000` so it will be accessable from `https://webmin.example.com`

## nginx

```
server {
    listen  443 ssl http2;
    server_name  webmin.example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate  /var/ini/ssl/example.com/public.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/ini/ssl/example.com/private.key;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/;
    }
}
```

## webmin

```
echo "referers=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" >> /etc/webmin/config
```

When requesting `https://example.com` the request is proxied to webmin, but I get this

```
If this is a legitimate link, you can allow links from this URL as follows :

Login to Webmin normally.
Go to the Webmin Configuration module.
Click on the Trusted Referrers icon.
...
```

I already have added the ip address to `referers=` in webmin config

... and have restarted webmin server

Comment: To the VtC crowd: Webmin is not inherently off-topic because it is not a control panel in the same sense as how cPanel/Plesk completely modify the system to fit those tools and normal administration becomes impossible, au contraire...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the original url used to access the webmin interface, i.e. `webmin.example.com` instead of the ip address.

See the webmin doc here:

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Running_Webmin_Under_Apache

OR trusted Referrers here:

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Webmin_Configuration